# /bin/csh not found (apt-get command not found) openSUSE Leap

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse

I am very very new to Linux and I don't know anything about it... I am just trying to Install SAP ABAP Trial version on Open SUSE Leap. I have already Installed it on my Windows Machine, but this time I am trying to install it on Mac M1 Pro.

when I am trying to run `install.sh` command to start final installation of SAP ABAP Trial version I am getting below error

```
/bin/csh not found 
You need a C shell to start the server
```

When I tried to install `csh` package using below command

```
sudo apt-get install csh
```

I am getting error message : `apt-get command not found`

[image]

Please help me... how can I install `csh` package?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 3):

opensuse is an `rpm` based distro, not `apt`.

If you run `cnf csh`, it will come and tell you which package to install, in this case, it is `tsch`.

`cnf` means `command not found` , and if you do not have that installed, then run `zypper in command-not-found`.

If you're running a gui, much of what can be changed, installed & removed, can be done through `yast2`. Highly recommended.

I have to ask... You are running opensuse on a M1, yes? Does that SAP software run on ARM? Or are you trying to install x86_64 binaries, which won't work?

Answer (score 2):

run `zypper install tcsh`. That will install csh.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar **(now solved)** problem with Geany in openSuse Leap15.4 when I tried to compile my php-files.

Geany's standard command for compiling is:' php -l "website.php" ' where php points to /usr/bin/php.

I am using php8. In my case the setup did not install anything else but php-cgi. Fully logical that Geany could not find /usr/bin/php

To solve this issue you need to go to

- tools
- Configuration Files
- Filetype Configuration
- Scripting Language
- filetypes.php

I changed the original:

```
[build-menu]    
FT_00_LB=_Compile
FT_00_CM=php -l "%f"
FT_00_WD=


[build-menu]
FT_00_LB=_Compile
FT_00_CM=php-cgi -l "%f"
FT_00_WD=
```

That's all